# Python3 thread pool: apply function to task generator

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.4

I need to apply a function, in parallel, to all items in a large generator. I don't want to buffer the returns, it's just a gigantic array of `None`.

I don't understand how to do this with the `concurrent.future` API.

What's the easiest and most efficient way to apply a function to items in a generator, through a thread pool with a worker cap, discarding the results?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's what I did. Given the following definitions:

```
from concurrent import futures
import itertools

func    = print          # any function
tasks   = iter(iterable) # any one-time-only iterator
workers = 10
```

This maps `func` to `tasks`, with a worker cap, discarding results:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = workers) as pool:
      initial = itertools.islice(tasks, workers)
      running = set(pool.submit(func, task) for task in initial)

      for task in tasks:
          done, _  = futures.wait(running, return_when = futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
          running -= done
          running.add(pool.submit(func, task))
```

Answer (score 0):

in  case you wish to extend the implementation for multiple objects whom iterations are like state-machine you can use a program that I have written.

https://github.com/talvezu/Python/blob/master/examples/concurrency/producer_consumer_generatored_thread_poll_with_inheritance.py

2 contexts.
one reading tasks from file (2 different objects representing 2 state-machines)
one context hold the thread-pool and any time a future is done it is using a thread-safe queue to notify that it is done, which causes the next() method to be invoked and continue the next iteration.

ones the object reaching "done" state it is no longer returned to the pool.